# Does text next to call to action buttons help or hinder the usability?

Tags: call-to-action, lean-ux

Should there be additional clarifying text near the button or should the button define the call to action by itself?

Comment: Normally text relating to a button is in the button or shown on hover. Do you have an example / mockup / screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: Here is an example of what I'm referring to - https://www.evernote.com/shard/s13/sh/2df21a3c-c4d4-4399-81cf-7ed7ec7c6b81/8a4e1431b3d57d9d25769867d154aa6f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button alone should define the call to action (specifying what the button will do / where it will take you). It should not depend on external text to explain *what* the action is.

You can however have additional text around it to give the user reasons *why* they specifically might want to *do* that action.

Comment: Are tooltips *external text explaining what the action is* in that respect, as well?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ooh, good question. I would say that, specifically for a button that is a call to action, a tooltip or hover should never be the key to understanding what the action is. You want to draw the user to interact with the button, and a tooltip is only displayed when the user has already been drawn there.